# libgdx in Android: how to handle escape key?

Tags: java, libgdx

In Android. I implement an InputProcessor and:

```
@override public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
```

When I press escape, no key is checked and the app exits. How do I check Escape key?

ps: in PC/MAC ,I can check Escape directly, and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode){
switch (keycode){
    case Keys.ESCAPE:
        Gdx.app.log("Monles", "ESC pressed");
        break;
    ...
```

Also, my app doesn't quit when I press ESCAPE, but if yours do, this will probably fix it:

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

Comment: after add: Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true); app do not quit now ,but I can't check in keyDown.

Comment: set Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true), and then I check key Back, it work. not Escape. Escape work at PC/MAC.

Answer (score 3):

First create an InputProcessor to handle the back key actions and then add it to a multiplexer so that other components still receive similar events.

```
      InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

                if ((keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Keys.BACK) )

                // Maybe perform other operations before exiting
                Gdx.app.exit();
                return false;
            }
        };


        InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(mStage,
                backProcessor);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

And enable catching the back key.

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

That's all there is. Good luck!

Comment: android handle key BACK and PC handle key Escape. you are great.